# Should askubuntu implement a "Humble-Bundle" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Since Linux support for the Humble Bundles is pretty highly publicized (including integration with the Ubuntu Software Center), should askubuntu implement a "humble-bundle" tag to address bundle related issues?  It seems like there are quite a few humble bundle questions here already.

Comment: Why not just keep using `games`? Probably no need to split games into different subtags is there?

Comment: I think the humble bundle brings different traffic and interest than a question about a game that's typically available in the repos, but it's a debateable point.  Hence, the meta topic.

Comment: Fair enough, I don't feel strongly one way or the other to post an answer, but if you want to go through and reorganize them all that wouldn't be bad, they need to be reviewed anyway.

Comment: if it is.. then maybe we should also implement a "steam" tag.. since steam is rolling out a linux client fairly soon.. 
just type in steam in search to see that it would be used in many cases ,more so probably more than a "Humble-Bundle" tag would be used.. (i think..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel as if this tag being created would invite fragmentation of [games](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/games) with other games. Maybe we should make a few subcategories of [games](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/games) that allude to being run in Wine,on being in the repos, without creating tags for every single game. This occurred on Arquade and via the actions of the cleanup processes, they have [over 100 untagged questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged). Since this invites anti-organization, we should not encourage creating tags for specific packages, except for the most important such as unity, USC, and Libreoffice, for example. Even then, we must still be cautious.

Comment: Someone needs to get data on how many humblebundle-related game questions we get.  If there are an enormous number,it makes more sense.   I know there seem to be a lot, but my observation is not at all scientific.   Also, most Humble buyers do not seem aware of whether their games are wine or java or whatever-based.  Otherwise, I do like the sub-category idea. (And of course they could be retagged....)

Comment: @belacqua [About 240](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=Humble+Bundle).